# Importing images Azure Machine Learning Studio

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-machine-learning-service

Is it possible to import images from your Azure storage account from within a Python script module as opposed to using the Import Images module that Azure ML Studio provides. Ideally I would like to use `cv2.imread()`. I only want to read in grayscale data but the Import Images module reads in RGB. 
Can I use the `BlockBlobService` library as if I were calling it from an external Python script?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you should be able to do that using Python. At the very least, straight REST calls should work.

Comment: Is there an example you could refer me to?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, I think you want to get the grayscale data of a image which comes from Azure Blob Storage via the method `cv2.imread` of `python-opencv2`.

I tried to write a python script using `azure-storage==0.20.3` package to do it. Here is my sample code as below.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobService
import numpy
import cv2

service = BlobService(account_name='<your storage account name>', account_key='<your storage account key>')
blob = service.get_blob_to_bytes('mycontainer', 'test.jpg')
print type(blob)
np_array = numpy.fromstring(blob, numpy.uint8)
print np_array
img = cv2.imdecode(np_array, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
```

If using the latest `azure-storage` package, make sure that using the code as below.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

service = BlockBlobService(account_name='<your storage account name>', account_key='<your storage account key>')
```

The code above works fine on local environment, but it doesn't work as a `Execute Python Script` module on the `Experiments` of Azure ML Studio, because of missing the required Python packages `azure-storage` & `cv2`. Then I tried to follow the document [`Adding Python Script as a Custom Resource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn955437.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_3) to add these packages, but failed that I realized the `python-opencv2` package is depended on the C native library `opencv2`.

**So per my experience, I think the simple & workaround way is that computing the grayscale data with the RGB data in `dataframe` from `Import Images` module of `OpenCV Library Modules`.**

Hope it helps.