# Azure Machine Learning Studio and OpenCV

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Has anyone successfully used the entire opencv library with Azure ML Studio and the Python Module? I know to use a python module that is not included in the ananconda version it must be uploaded in as a zip and from there you can use the entire library. Could someone explain to me exactly what to upload as a zip and then how to access specific functions of the opencv library once uploaded.

Comment: For anyone attempting to pair Azure ML and OpenCV that comes across this, my advice to you would be to find another way. ML Studio in my opinion can't handle images well, too slow. Instead of writing Python or R inside ML Studio, look into Azure Functions. In Functions you can write Python (and R if you install the extension) to execute on a schedule. Don't process images inside of ML Studio itself. Read your images into the Azure Function in your Python or R script and then write the data of the images to a blob - Then you can read the blob into ML Studio to do your analysis on.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to install it through `pip install opencv-python`

[image: pip install opencv-python]

Comment: It worked for me as well.
install package with pip as mentioned by @Oceinic

Answer (score 1):

Here is example of how to do it for R. Same logic applies for python as well - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gagarwal/2016/12/03/installing-r-package-in-azure-machine-learning/

Answer (score 1):

According to my tesing for your other SO thread [Importing images Azure Machine Learning Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081202/importing-images-azure-machine-learning-studio), it seems to not install `OpenCV` & its python module library in Azure ML Studio.

Meanwhile, I tried to install `OpenCV` for the Jupyter Notebook of Azure ML, but also failed because I don't know the password of the user `ubuser` for `Anaconda` installed on Ubuntu, so I could not install `opencv2` & `python-opencv2` via terminal of Jupyter.

Per my experience, the only possible way is that using Azure VM to install them and create a web serivce for calling from Azure ML.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help Peter. At this point of my project I was able to replace the functions from opencv with similar functions from skimage. As I touched upon in my question, the possible way to do it is via the zip method. My understanding is that because opencv is written in C++ and wrapped for python, the python opencv code is not quite accessible and user friendly.